# Setting up "emergency shutdown" for Google account triggered by entering special second password

Tags: gmail, google-account, passwords

Sometimes a captured person can be forced to disclose a password for his online services. It would be useful if those services have the ability to set up an additional password, which can tell the service that it is being accessed in an illegal way when this special password is typed instead of a normal password.

Imagine a person having to log in to Gmail and send dictated e-mail at gunpoint. By logging in with the second password, Gmail is expected to automatically send pre-defined e-mails to pre-defined addresses (like `I'm busted, don't trust this account`) and discretely append similar text to all sent e-mails (without the text appearing in "Sent" folder, obviously). It should be like TrueCrypt's hidden container, but for e-mails.

Can I set up such scheme with Google?

Comment: Great! I removed the " Are there alternative services that support this?" part of your question, as application recommendations are off-topic for this site.

Comment: Most Google services have a "Send Feedback" feature where you can request features such as this.

Comment: @Jerry101, Submitted the feedback with a link here.

Answer (score 1):

No, Gmail does not currently have such a feature.  It's unlikely that such a feature would be added.  (And if such a did feature did exist, what's to stop your hypothetical attacker from knowing about it, and sending himself an e-mail to make sure that you didn't activate it.)

Comment: The "append to each e-mail" option can be inactive. How whould you detect one-time emergency e-mail to pre-configured addresses?